# Cannot Debug Electron JS application in VSCode

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, electron, node-inspector

I am trying to develop a sample application for learning electron JS.
But unfortunately for me, the node debugger is not working for [this](https://github.com/simonschiller/electron-demo) particular project.

But when I tried debugging [electron-quick-start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) app it works, we can see the call stack and all.

lunch.json looks like this

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug Main Process2",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/main.js",
      "diagnosticLogging": true
    }
  ]
}
```

I am running on Linux machine with Node v7.4.0.

The error message I am getting on CALL STACK tab is
*`No Call stack available(vscode_backtrace:Internal error: TypeError: undefined is not a function)`*

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: This video does a good walkthrough on how to set it up: [Debugging Electron in VS Code](http://electron.rocks/debugging-electron-in-vs-code-again/). I tried it (on OSX) and it works – and it is also more trouble than it's worth right now for me. Console.log() and the Chrome dev tools provide more than adequate reporting. Maybe as my projects grow more complex it will be worth the effort.